# How to fetch supervisor id and supervisor name for all employees in ps_job

Tags: jobs, names, peoplesoft

I am new to peoplesoft system, there is one query to retrieve supervisor name and supervisor I'd from ps_names table for all the employees of ps_job table. 
Can anyone please tell me how to do this?
And can anyone please tell me the result variation using different join condition.

Answer (score 0):

In PS Query you create a query with the records job and names. PS Query will suggest to join on the common emplid fields, but since you want the name of the supervisor, refuse this suggestion. Add the join manually by adding a criterium that states that the supervisor id of job should be equal to the emplid field of names.

you have two join options:
standard: only the rows that have a match are returned, job rows with an empty supervisor id, or rows where the supervisor id has no corresponding entry in the names table are excluded
left outer join: all rows of job are shown including those with no corresponding match in names, the selected fields of the names table will be empty.

(making abstraction of effdt)